# Jetty http/2 client hangs fetching url

Tags: java, embedded-jetty, http2

I have a code (actually, copied from [jetty-project repo](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/jetty-9.4.x/jetty-http2/http2-http-client-transport/src/test/java/org/eclipse/jetty/http2/client/http/HttpClientTransportOverHTTP2Test.java)):

```
HTTP2Client http2Client = new HTTP2Client();
SslContextFactory sslContextFactory = new SslContextFactory();
HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient(new HttpClientTransportOverHTTP2(http2Client), sslContextFactory);
Executor executor = new QueuedThreadPool();
httpClient.setExecutor(executor);
httpClient.start();

ContentResponse response = httpClient.GET("https://www.google.com/");
```

For some reason it waits for response infinitely. What's the problem with it? I'm seeking for a working example of http/2 client usage to access some https url. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably did not configure ALPN.

Please refer to the [ALPN documentation](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/alpn-chapter.html) to enable ALPN for the JVM running your client code.

Comment: I selected `alpn-boon` version with respect to jdk version (`jdk 1.8.0_92` -> `alpn-boot 8.1.8.v20160420`). Then added `-Xbootclasspath/p:/Users/user/.../alpn-boot-8.1.8.v20160420.jar` to vm options. It still seems kinda tricky for me, but it works. Thank you!